# parameter index out of range mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

```
List<UserLoginDTO> userDTOList=new ArrayList<UserLoginDTO>();
UserLoginDTO user= null;
try {
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(NHMQueryConstant.GET_SEARCH_USER_DETAIL.toString());
    pstmt.setString(1,searchUser);  
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
    while (rs.next()) {
        user= new UserLoginDTO();

        //user= new UserLoginDTO();
        //String login= rs.getString("Login_ID");

        user.setUserId(rs.getInt("M_USER_ID"));
        user.setUserName(rs.getString("M_USER_NAME"));
        user.setLoginID(rs.getString("Login_ID"));
        user.setUserTypeID(rs.getInt("USER_TYPE_ID"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        user.setMobile(rs.getString("MOB_NO"));
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        userDTOList.add(user);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new NHMException(e.getMessage());
}

public static final StringBuilder GET_SEARCH_USER_DETAIL =
   new StringBuilder().
    append(" SELECT * FROM  m_user_master").
    append(" WHERE M_User_Name = IFNULL(NULL,M_User_Name)
               AND Login_id = IFNULL('?',Login_id) limit 1 ");
```

I m getting parameter index out of range in this code.
Kindly please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders in sql query shouldn't be quoted. Correct query:

```
public static final StringBuilder GET_SEARCH_USER_DETAIL = new StringBuilder().append(" SELECT * FROM m_user_master").append(" WHERE M_User_Name = IFNULL(NULL,M_User_Name)AND Login_id = IFNULL(?,Login_id) limit 1 ");
```